# how to fetch users with countries, cities, states by using containable behavior in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, associations, relation, cakephp-2.6

I have these models : 
**Country,State,City,User**
with relations :
**Country hasMany State, 
State hasMany City, 
City hasMany User,**

**State belongsTo Country, 
City belongsTo State, 
User belongsTo City,**

Now I want to fetch all the users with not only their cities but also countries and states.
 How can I do this?

Controller
**users/index**:

```
 public function index() {
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        $this->paginate = array('contain'=>array('State'));
        debug($this->Paginator->paginate());exit;
        $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
```

**output** :

```
    Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "State" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]

\app\Controller\UsersController.php (line 27)

array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'username',
            'city_id' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

Model **Country** :

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'State' => array(
        'className' => 'State',
        'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Model **State** :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Model **City** :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'State' => array(
        'className' => 'State',
        'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);


public $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'city_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Model **User** :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'City' => array(
        'className' => 'City',
        'foreignKey' => 'city_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: check containable http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: @Abhishek 
I have tried with containable behavior on User Model but getting error something like this : User model is not associated with model State and Country

Comment: You need to use containable the right way, as documented, as chained contain statement. Or use custom binding to make it one query with multiple left joins (hot tip: linkable behavior can do that for you out of the box).

Comment: show some code from model and controller for what you had tried

Comment: @Abhishek
I have edited the question

Comment: How about model , have you made any association there ?

Comment: @Abhishek 
yes I have made.

Comment: Error clearly shows that you have not made any association.

Comment: @Abhishek 
I have updated again with Model association

Comment: i hope with your code you will figure out issue on your own

Comment: @Abhishek
thanx for your response

Comment: @mark
I have followed the example from cookbook but it' not working.

Comment: @mark
I learned how to use containable as chained statement and got the solution I was looking for.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved. Thanks to the cakephp community.
**Controller** users/index

```
public function index() {
    //$this->User->recursive = 3;
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');

/*  $user = $this->User->find('all', array(
'contain' => array(
'City.name' => array(
'State.name'=>array('Country.name')
))));
        debug($user);exit;
    */  

$this->paginate = array('contain'=>array('City'=>array('State'=>array('Country'))));
//debug($this->Paginator->paginate());exit;
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

**View** users/index

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('city_id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('state_id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('country_id'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($user['User']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($user['User']['name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($user['City']['name'], array('controller' => 'cities', 'action' => 'view', $user['City']['id'])); ?>

        </td>

        <td>

            <?php echo $this->Html->link($user['City']['State']['name'], array('controller' => 'states', 'action' => 'view', $user['City']['State']['id'])); ?>
                </td>

        <td>

            <?php echo $this->Html->link($user['City']['State']['Country']['name'], array('controller' => 'countries', 'action' => 'view', $user['City']['State']['Country']['id'])); ?>
        </td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```